# Появляется рамка вокруг кнопки при наведении

Tags: html, button

При наведении на кнопку появляется рамка черного цвета с шириной в одной пиксель, не смотря на свойство `outline: none`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разобрались? В чем была причина?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что есть правило с модификатором :hover, в котором прописан border (или outline). Проверить можно, прописав для кнопки border:none!important (то же с outline), но не стоит оставлять это как готовое решение - такие костыли в дальнейшем могут только прибавить работы.

Comment: Та же самая ситуация.

Answer (score 0):

Поищи в стилях, что-то на подобии
`button:hover { border: 1px solid black; }`
И просто удали строку с этим стилем

Comment: У меня border имеет ширину 0px, я использую его только для скругления.

Comment: Если не решил, скинь код, посмотрю